# How to count items in a specific row from a multi lined string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> itms="""banana  cookie  cream  soda   lime  limes  apples
              desert  plate   cake  orange  milk   beans   
              juice   apple pie"""
```

I'm wondering how do you count items in a certain row from a multi lined string?

Example: The first row would return **7**

The Second would return **6**

and the last one would return **2** (due to "apple pie" only containing 1 white-space in-between it).

Comment: Check out the .split method

Comment: See `str.split` and `str.strip`, `str.split` takes an argument that indicates what it should split on. These two methods make this task relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little example that print's out the number of elements in a line.

```
import re
lines = [re.split(r'\s{2,}',x.strip()) for x in itms.split("\n")]
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print "line number : {0} has {1} elements".format(index, len(line))

line number : 0 has 7 elements
line number : 1 has 6 elements
line number : 2 has 3 elements
```

1) First, you want to put every `line` string into a list of `strings`

2) Then you break it up into its single elements so that every word in a line is on its own list.

3) From there on, we just have to get the length of the list's that contain `your words per line`.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [12]: itms="""banana  cookie  cream  soda   lime  limes  apples
    ...:               desert  plate   cake  orange  milk   beans
    ...:               juice   apple pie"""
```

Split your string into lines

```
In [13]: itms = [line.strip() for line in itms.split('\n')]

In [14]: itms
Out[14]:
['banana  cookie  cream  soda   lime  limes  apples',
 'desert  plate   cake  orange  milk   beans',
 'juice   apple pie']
```

Split the items on more than two spaces

```
In [15]: import re

In [16]: itms =  [re.split(r'\s\s+', line) for line in itms]

In [17]: itms
Out[17]:
[['banana', 'cookie', 'cream', 'soda', 'lime', 'limes', 'apples'],
 ['desert', 'plate', 'cake', 'orange', 'milk', 'beans'],
 ['juice', 'apple pie']]
```

Count the elements in each line

```
In [18]: for x in itms:
    ...:     print(len(x))
    ...:
7
6
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can count on the word divider always being two spaces, the following would return `[7, 6, 2]`:

```
[len(line.strip().split('  ')) for line in itms.split('\n')]
```

If the word divider is an arbitrary number of whitespace characters, you could use the regex module.

```
import re
[len(re.split(r'\s\s+', line.strip())) for line in itms.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two lines of code:

```
it = itms.split('\n')
for i in it: print(len(i.split()))
```

Comment: Except that it counts the last line wrong... it counts it as 3 not 2.